# My form is shifting to a backend page in php after clicking on Submit

Tags: php, html, web, webforms, submit

I am clicking on Submit button my form is getting submitted. I just wanted to submit the details, but not to visit the backend page or popup in it that the data have been submitted.

```
<form action="functionality\app_details.php" method="post">
    <!-- Name -->
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text">Name</span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Enter name">
    </div>
    <!-- Parent's name -->
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text">Parent's Name</span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" name="Fname" id="inputFname" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Father's Name">
        <input type="text" name="Mname" id="inputMname" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Mother's Name">
    </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger">submit</button>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to just submit it and nothing happen. just leave the action empty so it won't go anywhere.

you can also do this if you want the page not to refresh:

```
document.getElementById("enter you button id here").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault()
});
```

Comment: This will not work since it will post to same url as form is on. What you need to do is in javascript to prevent default on the event submit on the form, or, preventDefault on the click event on the button (will not catch forms posted with enter key)

Comment: yeah you can also do this if you want the page not to refresh. great patrik

Answer (score -1):

The data is sent to the page you put in action tag..
If you want to send the data to the same page

```
<form action="" method="post">
...
</form>
```

or use Ajax.

Comment: the answer below from hayvon adelan by using event listeneners is correct

Comment: he want the data to only go to the same page